# Creation of Directory Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Automatically - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to create directories in the Azure Data Lake Gen2 in this format. YYYY = 2020 (Current Year) -> MM = 10 (Current Month), DD = 28 (Current Date) and inside the Date folder I need to place the data file (Data.csv). i.e: /YYYY=2020/MM=10/DD=28/Data.csv.

**Code Used for Data.csv in Root Folder Directory:** **With the Help of @Jim Xu**

```
$username = "xyz@abc.com"
$password =ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username,$password)


#Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential | out-null

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential
$dataFactoryName=""
$resourceGroupName=""
# get dataFactory triggers
$triggers=Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$datas=@()
foreach ($trigger in $triggers) {
    # get the trigger run history
    $today = Get-Date
    $yesterday = $today.AddDays(-1)
     $splat = @{ 
        ResourceGroupName       = $trigger.ResourceGroupName
        DataFactoryName         = $trigger.DataFactoryName
        TriggerName             = $trigger.Name
        TriggerRunStartedAfter  = $yesterday
        TriggerRunStartedBefore = $today
   }
    
   $historys =Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerRun @splat
   if($historys -ne $null){
     # create date
     foreach($history in $historys){
        $obj =[PsCustomObject]@{
            'TriggerRunTimestamp '     = $history.TriggerRunTimestamp
            'ResourceGroupName '   =$history.ResourceGroupName
            'DataFactoryName' =$history.DataFactoryName
            'TriggerName '  = $history.TriggerName
            'TriggerRunId'= $history.TriggerRunId
            'TriggerType'=$history.TriggerType
            'Status' =$history.Status

        }
        # add data to an array
        $datas += $obj
     }
   } 
   
  
 }
 #  convert data to csv string
 $contents =(($datas | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine)

 # upload to Azure Data Lake Store Gen2

 #1. Create a sas token
 $accountName="testadls05"
 $fileSystemName="test"
 $filePath="data.csv"
 $account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName andywin7 -Name $accountName
 $sas= New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob  -ResourceType Service,Container,Object `
      -Permission "racwdlup" -StartTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) `
      -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2) -Context $account.Context
$baseUrl ="https://{0}.dfs.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}{3}" -f $accountName ,  $fileSystemName, $filePath, $sas
#2. Create file
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&resource=file"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = 0} -UseBasicParsing

#3 append data
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&action=append&position=0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = $contents.Length} -Body $contents -UseBasicParsing

#4 flush data
$endpoint =$baseUrl + ("&action=flush&position={0}" -f $contents.Length)
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -UseBasicParsing

#Check the result (get data)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $baseUrl -UseBasicParsing
```

If anyone is having suggestions, please do post. Thanks

Comment: @Jim Xu : Here is the new post. please do check this.

Comment: Is that you want to create a directory like  "/2020/10/28" then upload file to the directory?

Comment: I am able to fix that with the help of this @JimXu:   
 $YY = (Get-Date).year
 $MM = (Get-Date).month
 $DD = get-date –f dd
 
 $fileSystemName="dev"
 $filePath="triggers/YYYY=$YY/MM=$MM/DD=$DD/data.csv". Thanks for the help !

Comment: Since you have solved the issue by yourself, please post your answer.

Comment: Please see the answer posted by me !

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution:**

```
 $username = "xyz@abc.com"
 $password = Get-Content D:\Powershell\new\passwords\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content D:\Powershell\new\passwords\aes.key)
 $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username,$password)

 Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential

# Input Variables

 $dataFactoryName="dna-production-gen2"
 $resourceGroupName="DataLake-Gen2"

# get dataFactory triggers

$triggers=Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$datas=@()
foreach ($trigger in $triggers) {
    # get the trigger run history
    $today = Get-Date
    $yesterday = $today.AddDays(-1)
     $splat = @{ 
        ResourceGroupName       = $trigger.ResourceGroupName
        DataFactoryName         = $trigger.DataFactoryName
        TriggerName             = $trigger.Name
        TriggerRunStartedAfter  = $yesterday
        TriggerRunStartedBefore = $today
   }
    
   $historys =Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerRun @splat
   if($historys -ne $null){
     # create date
     foreach($history in $historys){
        $obj =[PsCustomObject]@{
            'TriggerRunTimestamp '     = $history.TriggerRunTimestamp
            'ResourceGroupName '   =$history.ResourceGroupName
            'DataFactoryName' =$history.DataFactoryName
            'TriggerName '  = $history.TriggerName
            'TriggerRunId'= $history.TriggerRunId
            'TriggerType'=$history.TriggerType
            'Status' =$history.Status

        }
        # add data to an array
        $datas += $obj
     }
   } 
   
  
 }

#  convert data to csv string

 $contents =(($datas | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine)

 # upload to Azure Data Lake Store Gen2

 #1. Create a sas token
 
  $accountName="dna2020gen2"
 
# $path = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"

 $YY = (Get-Date).year
 $MM = (Get-Date).month
 $DD = get-date –f dd
 
 $fileSystemName="dev"
 $filePath="triggers/YYYY=$YY/MM=$MM/DD=$DD/data.csv"
 $account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'DataLake-Gen2' -Name $accountName
 $sas= New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob  -ResourceType Service,Container,Object `
      -Permission "racwdlup" -StartTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) `
      -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2) -Context $account.Context
$baseUrl ="https://{0}.dfs.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}{3}" -f $accountName ,  $fileSystemName, $filePath, $sas

#2. Create file
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&resource=file"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = 0} -UseBasicParsing

#3 append data
$endpoint =$baseUrl +"&action=append&position=0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Content-Length" = $contents.Length} -Body $contents -UseBasicParsing

#4 flush data
$endpoint =$baseUrl + ("&action=flush&position={0}" -f $contents.Length)
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $endpoint -UseBasicParsing

#Check the result (get data)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $baseUrl -UseBasicParsing
```